# Order by desc with Textable Class

Tags: php, class, text

I want it to arrange the data in descending order.

Now the data is like this:

```
1
2
3
```

I want to sort data like this:

```
3
2
1
```

This is the code:

full code : http://www.phpkode.com/source/s/textable/textable/textable.class.php

```
function read_table(){
    $lines = file($this->filename);
    foreach ( $lines as $row ){
        if (strlen($row) > 1){
            $temp = explode("~", $row);
            $temp[count($temp) - 1] = rtrim($temp[count($temp) - 1]);
            $this->table[] = $temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello :) i really need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push the values into an array and then use `arsort()`, which will create an array  with values in descending order.